# .NET Framework 3.5 and System.Net.Http not found

Tags: system.net

I have a framework 3.5 project containing some asmx files. 
When I have exception in asmx methods, I want return an error response:

```
try{
...
...
catch (Exception ex)
{
    var errorResponse = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    {
        Content = new StringContent(ex.Message), ReasonPhrase = ex.Message
    };
    return errorResponse;
}
```

But I can't use HttpResponseMessage class because I can't reference Sytem.Net.Http namespace!

Can anyone help me?
Thx

Answer (score 1):

System.Net.Http was introduced in 4.0, there is no 3.5 version. That's not the right return type for asmx anyways, you should go look at System.Web.

Comment: Thank you Tratcher. I must to use. 3.5. What do you suggest to return error response?